# XSLT to get value of node in next loop

Tags: xslt

Below is the xml. Now I am looking for an xslt where in the first loop of `<ns0:EBLoop1>` when EB01 = 1 then I need to get the value of  `<EB05>PACKAGE A STANDARD PLAN</EB05>`  in the next EBLoop1.

How can I do this.

```
<ns0:EBLoop1>
  <ns0:EB>
    <EB01>1</EB01> 
    <EB05>This</EB05> 
    <EB07>0</EB07> 
  </ns0:EB>
  <ns0:MSG>
    <MSG01>Please See the Provider Manual</MSG01> 
  </ns0:MSG>
</ns0:EBLoop1>
<ns0:EBLoop1>
  <ns0:EB>
    <EB01>D</EB01> 
    <EB05>PACKAGE A STANDARD PLAN</EB05> 
    <EB07>0</EB07> 
  </ns0:EB>
</ns0:EBLoop1>
<ns0:EBLoop1>
  <ns0:EB>
    <EB01>F</EB01> 
    <EB03>30</EB03> 
    <EB07>0</EB07> 
  </ns0:EB>
</ns0:EBLoop1>
```

Thanks,
Gopi

Comment: This XML is missing a namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the context node is your `EBLoop1` element, you can get the next one with xpath:

```
../following-sibling::ns:EBLoop1[1]/ns:EB/EB05
```

But you need to define your namespace and make use of the prefix in your xpath.